How an application is Identified by the other applications and the OS?
Dear StackOverflow community,
I am reaching out to inquire about "application identities." Recently, our company's IT manager has prohibited the use of certain applications such as "OneDrive" and "Telegram Messenger" on our machines. These restrictions have been enforced through the Kaspersky security package. When attempting to run these applications, users receive a warning stating, "You are not permitted to run the XYZ application on this device." This situation has made me question how security software or operating systems like Kaspersky, Windows, or Linux identify such applications. Do they look for a specific signature or just the application name?
As I have only developed code for personal and engineering use and have not attempted to release my software, I am unfamiliar with how this process works. I am curious whether individuals with access to source code can replicate another application's signature or alter the signature to make it appear as an entirely different application.
I greatly appreciate your time and assistance.

They use a lot of techniques, because no one technique is reliable. No; you cannot forge a code signature unless you have access to the private key (that's the point of code signing), but code signing is not the only way (or even the primary way) that scanning tools detect programs. Your first question likely belongs on serverfault.com. Your second on security.stackexchange.com (but in both cases, search first).

@robNapier thank you very much. My search was not yielding to any useful results since I did not know where to look for the answers. I was looking for some keywords to search. Thank you for the site suggestions.
